# Meaning of the phrase "if we are to do something"?

Tags: meaning, subjunctives

Here is the context:

> First, we have to understand the nature of the virus, **if we are to** overcome it.

Does it mean *if we want to overcome it*?

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-to-do-something. This link may help.

Comment: It assumes that you want to overcome it rather than stating it. The meaning is that the *necessary condition* for overcoming the virus is to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "**be to do something**" can have [4 meanings](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-to-do-something) - depending on context:

**a) used to talk about arrangements for the future**

b) used to give an order or to tell someone about a rule

c) used to say or ask **what someone should do or what should happen**

d) used to ask how something can be done

> First, we have to understand the nature of the virus, **if we are to**
> overcome it.

In your context is in meaning a). It is talking about arrangements for the future for overcoming virus diseases, by understand their nature.

The answer for your last question:

If **we are to** overcome it = if **we plan** to overcome it **in future**.