# What is the meaning and role of "to" in "if these beautiful animals are to survive"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, infinitives, to-infinitive

> If we are **to** succeed in this enterprise, we shall need to plan everything very carefully.

> The time has come for action if these beautiful animals are **to** survive.

The "**to**" in the first example is used to introduce an aim when you are saying what must be done in order to achieve it.
We can omit "if we are" in the first example.
However, we can't omit "if these beautiful animals are" in the second one.

Therefore, I'm not sure what role the "**to**" in the second one has.

1. What is the meaning and role of the "**to**" in the second one?
2. What is the reason "if these beautiful animals are" can't be removed even though "if we are" can be removed.

Comment: Sorry but you don't know what "if" means?

Comment: @Lambie I know the meaning of it. I'll edit the post.

Comment: If we are to understand each other, the post requires clarification. Is that one I just said clear? :)

Comment: Both sentences use _exactly the same_ construction, but with the clauses in  a different order.  "If these beautiful animals are to survive, the time has come for action."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [meaning of the phrase "if we are to do something"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162325/meaning-of-the-phrase-if-we-are-to-do-something) Also [How Can I know if is "that is" "it is" "to be"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217488/) and [If you do sth v. If you are to do sth](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303345/) and [When should the phrase "If X were to do X"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208988/), among others.

Comment: @KateBunting: There's *something* different. We can remove initial ***If we are*** in the first one, and the utterance still means more or less the same thing. But I'm not convinced the end result is syntactically valid if we remove corresponding ***if these beautiful animals are*** from the second. Even rearranging the sequence to ***To survive, the time has come for action*** doesn't seem to save it. But I'm not *exactly* sure if the problem concerns the omitted subject or the nature of the primary assertion (*We shall need to...* OR *The time has come to...*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does the "are to" in "The time has come for action if these beautiful animals are to survive." mean "will"?

Comment: You *could* replace ***are to survive*** with ***are going to survive***, and both versions would almost always be interpreted as having exactly the same meaning. You *can't* use ***will*** there. But I don't find ***going to*** very idiomatic. ***If we are to [do X],* [Y must happen]* is quite clear and succinct. But ***If we are going to...*** pointlessly raises confusion as to whether Y only needs to happen ***if it is our intention** to do X* (which we might decide we don't want anyway). When in doubt, Keep It Simple

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the great answer. What does the "which" in "(which we might decide we don't want anyway)" refer to?

Comment: You really should stop trying to assign "specific meaning" to each word in an English utterance. The word "which" is primarily a "function word" - it's primarily just a compoent within a syntactic structure, not a "content word" with a clear-cut meaning, like a ***noun***. My bracketed aside above could have been written as *(we might decide we don't want **to do X** anyway)*. If you were already able to understand that meaning before asking what "which" refers to, I suggest you stop asking about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a way of referring to a future itinerary, schedule, agenda,  or a plan,  directive, goal, intention, etc:

> You **are to spend** three days at the hotel and each night you will have dinner with a prospective customer.
>
> If I **am to spend** three days at the hotel, I'll need to bring a suitcase with a change of clothing.

> If we **are to succeed** in this enterprise, we shall need to plan everything very carefully.

If succeeding in this enterprise is our goal and intention, we shall need to ...

> The time has come for action if these beautiful animals **are to survive**.

If the survival of these animals is the goal, the time has come for action.

Comment: Does the "am to" in "If I am to spend three days at the hotel, I'll need to bring a suitcase with a change of clothing." mean "will"?

Comment: There is  overlap in meaning but they are not identical.  Consider the difference between "If I'm expected to do X" vs "I will do X". It is the difference of expectation vs intention.  But one can establish much the same meaning with "If I *will be spending* three days..."

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is saying that action is necessary to achieve the goal of helping the animals to survive. It is understood that some group of people will need to be the ones taking action with the goal of helping the animals. Some paraphrases:

- The time has come for action if *we want* these beautiful animals to survive.
- The time has come for action *in order for* these beautiful animals to survive.

Comment: It might be worth adding another paraphrase, for ***so that** [these beautiful animals **survive**]*, because that removes the need for the potentially confusing infinitive marker ***to***. As can be seen more clearly in the singular version (not exactly the most elegant sentence I've ever written! :) *The time has come for action **so that** this beautiful animal **survives***.